# Running out of memory for 2D arrays in C++/CLI?

Tags: multidimensional-array, c++-cli, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm dealing with 10 of arrays, some of which are doubles 1024x1392.

I've tried to dynamically allocate them on the heap with:

```
double **x_array;

    x_array = new double*[NUM_ROWS];
for(int i=0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
    x_array[i] = new double[NUM_COLS];
}

        for(int ix=0; ix < NUM_COLS; ix++) {
            for(int iy=0; iy < NUM_ROWS; iy++) {
                x_array[ix][iy]=(x1y1*(ix+1) + x2y1*(iy+1) + x3y1);
                //y_array[ix][iy]=(x1y2*(ix+1) + x2y2*(iy+1) + x3y2);
            }
        }
    }
```

but I still get errors saying

```
unhandled exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEGException: External Component has thrown an exception. at line 106
```

and 106 is where I begin initializing the array in the code above:

```
    x_array = new double*[NUM_ROWS];
```

Am I really running out of space, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Windows 7, VS 2008, unsure about compiler. Thanks for catching me again :P

Comment: For the record, 10 arrays of 1024*1392 doubles on a system where `sizeof(double)==8` comes to 114032640 bytes, or 108.75MB.

Comment: BTW well done for getting it right w.r.t. `arrays of pointers to arrays` vs `arrays of arrays`. Your way is good because you get a nice friendly `double**` type; that said, `std::vector` is easier.. And what did your debugger say?

Comment: The desktop I'm using has 8GB of RAM which should be able to handle it, shouldnt it?

Comment: The documentation for [`SEHException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception.aspx) explicitly says that out of memory errors are mapped to [`OutOfMemoryException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx) instances, so clearly your problem is **not** (directly) memory related. You probably have a regular old access violation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your array indices transposed:

```
    for(int ix=0; ix < NUM_COLS; ix++) {
        for(int iy=0; iy < NUM_ROWS; iy++) {
            x_array[ix][iy]=(x1y1*(ix+1) + x2y1*(iy+1) + x3y1);
```

should be:

```
    for(int iy=0; iy < NUM_ROWS; iy++) {
        for(int ix=0; ix < NUM_COLS; ix++) {
            x_array[iy][ix]=(x1y1*(ix+1) + x2y1*(iy+1) + x3y1);
```

or if you really have to keep the cache-hostile loop ordering for some reason:

```
    for(int ix=0; ix < NUM_COLS; ix++) {
        for(int iy=0; iy < NUM_ROWS; iy++) {
            x_array[iy][ix]=(x1y1*(ix+1) + x2y1*(iy+1) + x3y1);
```

Comment: Thanks paul, but I'm working with code from MATLAB (where they're transposed) so I'm keeping it this way for now to simplify the matrix manipulations.

Comment: @Androo: well you can keep the (cache-hostile) loop order if you want, but you will still need to fix the order of the array indices. C/C++ et al are all row major. Your array indices are going out of bounds because you have iy and ix transposed, hence the crash.

Comment: Thank you very much paul. I followed your suggestion and it worked. I might run into some trouble (from switching the X and Y) down the line, but that can be adjusted later, at least I know the source of the problem.